# How to bind a checkbox to an already existing checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Product attribute Checkbox` on my website and it will update products list with ajax and javascript `onchange` event.

I added all of my code on [**Here (jsfiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/3x1ybuwd/44/).

**HTML**

```
<input data-option-ids="1358" id="specification-input-21-1358" type="checkbox">
<label class="filter-item-name" for="specification-input-21-1358">Only Available Product</label>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#specification-input-21-1358').change(function() {
    //ajax
});
```

I can't modify this code because it's part of a module which works for all of my attribute `checkboxes` and it is dynamically created and works fine.

I added a **another** checkbox with different style on top of my page and I want it to work **same as** that checkbox. My purpose is customers don't miss that they can use this checkbox.(first checkbox is part of attribute filters)

second checkbox HTML :

```
<div class="availButton">
    <p dir="rtl" style="text-align: left;">show only available products:</p>
    <div class="slideThree">
        <input id="slideThree" name="check" type="checkbox">
        <label for="slideThree">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's my current code to bind first checkbox to second one:

```
$('#slideThree').click(function()  { < -- - this works fine.
    $('#specification-input-21-1358').click();
});

$('#specification-input-21-1358').click(function() {
    if ($('#slideThree').length) {
        if ($('#slidethree').checked) < -- - problem is here.
        $('#slideThree').attr('checked', false);
        else
            $('#slideThree').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

> - problem is that second checkbox will not change if i click first one.
> - another problem is that if i refresh the page fist checkbox remains Checked but second one will not be checked.

More details about my code:

I have an Ajax Filter module in my code which has some `checkboxes` (same as Amazon), every checkbox is an attribute of my products. So when I check one of them, product list of website will be updated with ajax.
One of this `checkboxes` is : `show only avail Product` and if I click it, it  updates products list with ajax to show only available products.
I also added a another checkbox (with different style) to top of this page which is same as this one. My purpose is customers don't miss that they can use this checkbox.
and I want both `checkboxes` to work the same.
So, if the customer checks one of them the other one has to be checked. and if they uncheck one of them the other has to be unchecked.

Comment: if you check jsfiddle , first click works fine i mean i can make that attribute being clicked well. problem is that when i click this attribute second one (slidetree) checkbox doesn't change.

Comment: (document).on('change','selector', function (){}). Add dollar in the beginning.

Comment: no change. please try it on jsfiddle.

Comment: You have already noted that `< -- - problem is here.` part. You can see that `$('#slidethree').checked` have all letters in lowercase but in `html` `T` is in uppercase as `slideThree`.

Comment: it makes no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
  $('#specification-input-21-1358, #slideThree').click(function() {
    if ($('#slideThree').length)
      $('#specification-input-21-1358, #slideThree').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/jve5gn6m/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go is to add a class attribute to the two element

```
<input data-option-ids="1358" id="specification-input-21-1358" class="specification-input-21-1358" type="checkbox">
```

then you can perform your ajax call with this.

```
$('.specification-input-21-1358').change(function() {
   //ajax
});
```

Comment: you didn't read my question i guess. ajax call works correctly. i just want bind second one to first one.

Comment: please sea jsfiddle

Comment: Now I understand your question.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below:

```
$('#slideThree').click(function() {
    $('#specification-input-21-1358').click();
});

$('#specification-input-21-1358').click(function() {
    if ($('#slideThree').length) {  
        $('#slideThree').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

Your can test it below.

```js
//if product page is refreshing while ajax filter is already clicked it will work inverse (when checked ajax filter is uncheked)

$('#slideThree').click(function() {
  $('#specification-input-21-1358').click();
});

$('#specification-input-21-1358').click(function() {
  if ($('#slideThree').length) {
    $('#slideThree').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  }
});
// it's ajax filter and will updated product list of website with ajax and i don't want modify this
$('#specification-input-21-1358').change(function() {
  var i = n(this),
    r = i.closest("div[data-optionsGroupId]"),
    u = new t;
  u.requestProductsForSelectedFilters(r, i)
});
```

```css
.availButton p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: m2hweb;
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  direction: ltr;
}

.slideThree::before {
  content: 'ON';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #00bf00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree::after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.slideThree input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slideThree input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  left: 43px;
}

.slideThree label {
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
}

.slideThree {
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.slideThree::after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="availButton">
  <p dir="rtl" style="text-align: left;">Show Only Available product :</p>

  <div class="slideThree"><input id="slideThree" name="check" type="checkbox"> <label for="slideThree"></label></div>
</div>

<ul class="checkbox-list">
  <li class="checkbox-item checkbox">
    <input data-option-ids="1358" id="specification-input-21-1358" type="checkbox">
    <label class="filter-item-name" for="specification-input-21-1358" data-originaltext="Available Product">Available Product</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```